# Ramdajs: How to filter a list based on a object property?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

```js
const abby = {name: 'Abby', attributes: {age: 7, hair: 'blond'}};
const fred = {name: 'Fred', attributes: {age: 12, hair: 'brown'}};
const rusty = {name: 'Rusty', attributes: {age: 10, hair: 'brown'}};
const alois = {name: 'Alois', attributes: {age: 15, disposition: 'surly'}};
const kids = [abby, fred, rusty, alois];

console.log = function(text) {
$('#console').append($('<div>').text(text));
};

// current code
console.log(R.filter(R.compose(R.propEq('hair', 'blond'), R.props('attributes')))(kids));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>

<div id="console"></div>
```

I want to get the objects whose hair is 'blond'. I tried using compose but unluckily it doesn't work. I am still new with ramda.

Answer (score 4):

Your initial attempt is almost correct; `R.props('attributes')` should have been `R.prop('attributes')` instead:

```
R.filter(R.compose(R.propEq('hair', 'blond'), R.prop('attributes')))(kids)
```

However you may find it easier to use [`pathSatisfies`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pathSatisfies) if you need to assert against a nested property:

> Returns true if the specified object property at given path satisfies the given predicate; false otherwise.

```js
const {filter, pathSatisfies, equals} = R;

const abby = {name: 'Abby', attributes: {age: 7, hair: 'blond'}};
const fred = {name: 'Fred', attributes: {age: 12, hair: 'brown'}};
const rusty = {name: 'Rusty', attributes: {age: 10, hair: 'brown'}};
const alois = {name: 'Alois', attributes: {age: 15, disposition: 'surly'}};
const kids = [abby, fred, rusty, alois];

console.log(

  filter(pathSatisfies(equals('blond'), ['attributes', 'hair']), kids)

)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

**References**

1. [props](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#props)
2. [prop](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#prop)
3. [pathSatisfies](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pathSatisfies)

Answer (score 0):

it is year 2020, I guess use pathEQ is much simple

```
const R = require("ramda");
let out = "";
const abby = { name: "Abby", attributes: { age: 7, hair: "blond" } };
const fred = { name: "Fred", attributes: { age: 12, hair: "brown" } };
const rusty = { name: "Rusty", attributes: { age: 10, hair: "brown" } };
const alois = { name: "Alois", attributes: { age: 15, disposition: "surly" } };
const kids = [abby, fred, rusty, alois];
out = R.filter(R.pathEq(["attributes", "hair"], "blond"))(kids);
```